# MinGW Compilation Problem

Tags: c++, c, mingw32

I just installed MinGW using the automatic installer MinGW-get-inst that I found on their website. I am using eclipse to write my C++ programs. My code compiles fine, and I get a .exe file. However, when I try to open this executable, I get the error that **libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll** is missing from my computer. I have located this file under MinGW\bin so I know it exists.

This is for all C/C++ programs, I am testing with a simple hello-world program. Any fixes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the MinGW\bin directory is on the path from where you are running application.

If you were running the resulting executable, say `a.exe` for example, from a CMD window do the following to check that MinGW\bin is on the path.

`set PATH`

At this point you will see the current value for the command path.  Make sure the MinGW\bin directory is in it somewhere.